# Stats about close reasons used?

Tags: support, data-explorer, close-reasons

Are there any stats about the percentage of close reasons used to close questions

- Successfully (preferably, based on the number of closed questions)
- Unsuccessfully (alternatively, the total percentags of close votes cast by users)

?

Is there any way to get this from the query explorer?

Comment: Probably not from SEDE, as close votes expire.

Comment: @waiwai ah, true. Hadn't thought of that. @Developers, is there a chance of getting that info? (Just if it isn't too much trouble, I'm just looking for background info for a feature suggestion)

Comment: Just in case somebody stumbles over this like me: be aware that off-topic/community specific reasons are not differentiated further in the data explorer. See [Please add the individual close-as-off-topic reason in the Data Explorer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/297750/please-add-the-individual-close-as-off-topic-reason-in-the-data-explorer) for a feature request.

Comment: I think that [New 10K tool: question close statistics](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/257449/335251) (from way back in 2015) sort of accomplishes what this request was looking for, right? (If so, should this be tagged as [status-completed]?)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Unsuccessfully -- no, when close votes disappear from the system, they are hard-deleted, so they physically don't exist anymore (except in backups, I suppose).

Successfully -- yes, the `CloseReasonId` is actually stuffed into the `Comment` field in `PostHistory` (I've updated [the docs](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2677/database-schema-documentation-for-the-public-data-dump-and-data-explorer) to reflect this). I [created a query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/s/791/distribution-of-close-reasons) to summarize how frequently questions are closed by type of close. You can calculate the percentages from this quite easily.

Also, for the curious, I [created another query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/s/792/how-many-questions-have-i-helped-to-close) to show how *you* have voted to close in successfully closed questions.

Comment: Sweet, exactly what I was looking for (well, minus the "Unsuccessfully" part, but I kind of expected that). Thank you very much!

Comment: @Pekka: You're welcome! I was curious why there was no CloseReasonId column in PostHistory, so it was good to figure this out.

Comment: @Jon, where is the vote close reason stored? Nothing makes it to the history table unless the post is closed. This info, however, must get stored somewhere. The most common close reason is noted if more than one reason is used. Does the votes table have extra columns not visible on SEDE? Like a closeReasonId or something?

Comment: @Mohamad: [Add close reasons to the data dump and to Data Explorer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/99311/add-close-reasons-to-the-data-dump-and-to-data-explorer)

Answer (score 5):

As the CloseReason are now part of SEDE I've created queries that use those tables:

Here is the [close statistics for non-deleted posts](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/259829/count-per-close-reason)

```
select case 
       when crt.id in (1,101) then 'duplicate' 
       when crt.id in (2,102) then 'off topic'
       else crt.name
       end as [name]
       , count(ph.id) as [count]
from posthistory ph
inner join CloseReasonTypes crt 
        on crt.id = cast(ph.comment as int)
where posthistorytypeid = 10
group by case 
       when crt.id in (1,101) then 'duplicate' 
       when crt.id in (2,102) then 'off topic'
       else crt.name
       end
```

Here I combined the two separate duplicate and off topic close reasons into one, based on @ShadowWizards comment. In the next query I leave that out so you can see if the change of reasons and the subtle new guidance that came with their introduction made a difference for you.

And this one shows your own [favourite close reasons](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/259830/my-close-reason-stats?UserId=187606):

```
select crt.name
     , count(ph.id) as [count]
from posthistory ph
inner join CloseReasonTypes crt 
        on crt.id = cast(ph.comment as int)
where posthistorytypeid = 10
and   text like '%"Id":' + ##Userid:string## + ',%'
group by crt.name
```

Final note: SEDE is update once a week and doesn't hold deleted posts.

Comment: Nice! However, two bugs: http://i.stack.imgur.com/BAdSP.png can those reasons be merged?

Comment: But aren't they technically different reasons, also with slightly different characteristics?

Comment: Looks like the close reason name was simply changed over time, no?

Comment: No, yes, maybe. Anyway... a compromise, is this fine?

Comment: Perfect! Already got my +1 but I would have given another one ;)