# How many unsuccessful close votes have ever been cast?

Tags: support, vote-to-close, closed-questions, statistics

On SO, how many unsuccessful close votes have ever been cast on questions with a total of at least two closevotes?

How are they distributed? (Dupe, Off-topic, NaRQ, ....)

How has their number and distribution developed over time?

How has the ratio of new questions to closed questions to unsuccesfully closed questions developed over time?

Has the number of unsuccessfully closevoted questions grown with the overall number of questions?

This is something only the devs can answer, if at all. (Related feature request [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/83006/let-sede-users-get-hold-of-data-on-unsuccessful-close-votes).)

Comment: recent change that made this statistics less interesting is that one can now [re-cast expired close votes and flags](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/250223/165773)

Answer (score 1):

A recent example is my own question ["Harris' “Algebraic Geometry”, quantum dynamics on varieties, and a more-than-monetary reward"](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/88133/harris-algebraic-geometry-quantum-dynamics-on-varieties-and-a-more-than-mone), which peaked-negative with a -7 downvotes and 4 votes to close.

To be sure, as folks expressed their concerns, I was able to address them.  Moreover, by sheer good luck, Joseph Landsberg published a book in December that surveyed a class of objects that included precisely the ones I was asking about; referencing Landsberg's book helped folks to appreciate the point of the question.

In consequence, the question has now gained back three votes, and is continuing to attract now-positive comments, and so I am reasonably hopeful that both the question and its answer(s) will end with net vote-scores that are solidly positive.

**Elevator Summary**  For me as "asker" and for everyone commenting on this particular question, the MOF system is working pretty well ... for the simple reason that MOF commenters are respecting the fundamental academic principle: "be quick to critique and slow to censor."

Comment: This is interesting, but it seems far too specific to your post to really qualify as an answer to Pekka's question.