# How many downvotes have I ever cast?

Tags: support, down-votes, statistics

How many downvotes have I ever cast?

Including votes on since deleted questions?

Is there a way to find out?

Comment: Different from my [other stats request](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/106653/how-many-unsuccessful-close-votes-have-ever-been-cast) today, this one is out of vain curiosity.

Comment: I was under the impression that the number of votes (up / down) shown on user profiles included those against deleted posts.

Comment: @DMA nope - see [Eeeek! I'm missing 650 downvotes, and 300 upvotes](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/90495)

Comment: Ah. For some reason I was thinking the change happened the other way around. >.<

Comment: Do you accept `too freaking many/less` as an answer?

Comment: @Padded I was hoping to get a *bit* more of a specific reply. :) -

Comment: Do you mean "now" or "ongoing"? If the latter... for what purpose? (actually, that kinda applies either way)

Comment: @Marc ongoing; I mean all votes ever cast. As to why - as said, vain curiosity - the desire to know how many questions I downvoted have been deleted. If it's a lot of work to find out, don't bother. (The other stats request is serious though - I'd much appreciate feedback on that, as I think too many bad questions are "getting away" because they fail to accumulate the necessary close votes.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've cast [756 down votes](https://api.stackexchange.com/2.0/users/138112?order=desc&sort=reputation&site=meta.stackoverflow&filter=!22bANZpnLvFv---RkJATq) on Meta at the time of this posting. To mess around with the request, [check out the API console](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/users-by-ids#order=desc&sort=reputation&ids=138112&filter=!22bANZpnLvFv---RkJATq&site=meta.stackoverflow). The vote counts returned by the API are inclusive of votes on deleted content, as you'll note by the fact that the respective vote counts are higher than those displayed in your profile.

Comment: Oh cool, thanks! That already helps a lot.

Comment: Aye. You can also get your full list of associated accounts via the API, but it seems that it's not possible (well, at least from what I could see in the console options) to create a filter that will return the associated account list with the additional vote count data (so you're stuck querying each site individually, if you want a grand total).