# 100 view requirement for vote expiry should not be based on total views

Tags: discussion, feature-request, voting, vote-to-close, views

Currently vote (e.g. to close/reopen) can [expire](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/97556/close-votes-expire-too-soon-for-low-traffic-tags/97581#97581) n days after the last vote, provided the question has 100 total views.

The 100 total views requirement is intended to avoid votes failing and an issue slipping under the radar simply because a question attracts low numbers of views.

In practice this means that for many votes on older questions this requirement has already been met when the first vote is placed. Close and reopen votes are disproportionately unlikely to succeed on older slow traffic questions. (There's no direct evidence of this because of [the lack of available data](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/83006/153020), although experience with [this clean up](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/119713/mass-clean-up-of-career-development-questions) suggests it is a problem).

**Proposal**: a new vote "resets" this 100 view requirement. 100 views should be required since the first vote in the current vote.

Comment: Suggestion based on [this post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/83006/let-sede-users-get-hold-of-data-on-unsuccessful-close-votes/109770#comment320840_109770)

Comment: upvoted, :) we are going to implement this

Comment: @waffles no objection from me, but I maintain that 90% of crap questions have <100 lifetime views anyway. Particularly on SE 2.0 sites, etc.

Comment: There's crap, and then there's 'fun' and it's derivatives. There are lots of broken windows out there with tons of views and votes that some of us are trying to clean up for oyu.

Answer (score 5):

+1 for this proposal.

I have an additional suggestion: could the view count only increment when the question is viewed by users who actually have the vote for close/reopen privilege?

Comment: I think there was a past post suggesting basing the timeout on that, but it was suggested it's quite hard to count viewers with vtc privilege.

Comment: 100 views was seen as a good estimate of a sensible number of viewers with close.