# Do re-open votes expire?

Tags: support

I have seen it mentioned places that re-open votes expire, but the [FAQ question on Reopening](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/36415/158605) makes no mention of that.

Do re-open votes expire, and if so how long does it take until they expire?

In addition, is there any way to view the total number of re-open votes a question has received over it's lifetime, such as with the [SE data explorer](https://data.stackexchange.com/)?

**Edit**

I have found a few meta links referencing re-open votes expiring, and am now trying to determine if these are current or not.

- [Answer stating that close and reopen votes expire after 2 days](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/33949/158605)
- [Newer answer stating that close votes close after 4 days and 100 views, and that the same will likely be implemented for re-open votes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/97581/158605)
- [Another answer re-affirming the above answer about re-open votes expiring after 4 days](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/97594/158605)

The last link seems to be the most current, however I am hoping that someone who knows the current expiration rule can confirm this. I also would like to know if there is a way to see total re-open vote counts anywhere.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're looking for.  The link you provided explains clearly what the new close/re-open policy is.  Are you *just* looking for a way to measure total votes in the data explorer?  It sounds like that's really the crux of your question, though it's thrown in as a sort of afterthought

Comment: @AdamRackis I found that link after I posted the question thanks to a link within a link from your answer. In the process of finding it, I also found answers containing other policies on re-open votes, so wanted to know what the current rule was for re-open votes expiring.

Comment: that's fine - that comment of mine was from like an hour ago.  That's ancient history :)  You've already explained what's going on, and I even upvoted your feature request

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<strike>Yes, re-open votes expire after two days, per Jeff's [famous answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/33949/155403)</strike>

> declining -- you can always cast a reopen vote if the post gets
>   closed.
>
> Also note that all close votes automatically expire after two days.
>
> (and for that matter reopen votes, or any other vote that attempts to
>   reach a threshold -- otherwise, over an absurdly long period of time,
>   say 10 years, everything would reach the threshold eventually through
>   a tiny trickle of accumulated votes)

It looks like, per the link you provided, this policy has been changed:

> We now use a form of sliding expiration, so as long as close/reopen
>   votes keep arriving at the rate of at least one every 4 days, they
>   will not expire.
>
> Once the votes do expire, vote aging happens every 24 hours, so you
>   can expect the remaining very old close/reopen votes to expire at the
>   rate of 1 per day after that, unless of course someone casts another
>   close/reopen vote in which case the expiration timer resets to 4 days.
>
> Also, if the question has <= 100 views, no expiration on close (or
>   reopen) votes is done at all.

---

Per Tim's comment below, you [cannot access expired close / re-open votes in the data explorer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/83006/155403)

Comment: That doesn't appear to be true anymore. I'm browsing meta, and a bunch of changes has been implemented since then. It also doesn't answer my question of how can I find a count of re-open votes.

Comment: @Rachel - Well I don't have an answer to your second question about the data explorer.  Do you have any documentation to suggest that re-open / close votes no longer expire after 2 days?

Comment: I found a few questions/answers on meta like [this one](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/97581/158605) showing changing rules for close/reopen votes. I am trying to determine what the current rule is.

Comment: @Rachel - if there are Meta links implying that the rules are changed, can you please add them to your question?

Comment: Sure, they've been added. I think the 3rd link I added is the most recent one, but I am not sure and would like to have someone who actually knows the current rules to confirm this.

Comment: @Rachel The answer to the second question is that you [cannot get this information](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/83006/let-sede-users-get-hold-of-data-on-unsuccessful-close-votes-for-stats), by the way.

Comment: Thanks @Tim - added that to my answer -- I assume you wouldn't mind.

Comment: Well, to be a bit more clear, you can [query for close/re-open votes](http://data.stackexchange.com/meta/query/edit/62680) so long as they haven't expired (`VoteTypeId` 6 and 7, respectively), but it's not enough to give you the clear picture over the life of the question.

Comment: @TimStone Thanks. Do you think it would be appropriate to re-raise the suggestion a year later? I am more interested in getting re-open votes than close votes for smaller sites whose questions don't get as much traffic. Some popular closed questions such as [this one](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/q/23075/1130) are up for deletion on P.SE, and in the process of trying to salvage some of them I noticed that re-open votes disappearing. I am curious how many overall re-open votes these questions have gotten.

Comment: @Rachel - write a feature request, but make sure you give your specific reasons, so as to differentiate your request from Pekka's (and prevent it from being closed as a dupe).

Comment: @Rachel waffles declined that request only a few weeks ago, so his position is unlikely to have changed.

Comment: @TimStone, Adam: Thanks, I've created another question about it [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/123804/158605). My primary reason for wanting to query total re-open votes is to determine community support for closed questions on lower-traffic SE sites. I find it extremely hard to get questions re-opened on the smaller sites, and if enough people have attempted to re-open a question I wish to bring that to the moderator's attention so they can use their super powers to bypass the 5 votes in 4 days requirement.