# Viewing total re-open votes in SE Data Explorer?

Tags: feature-request, data-explorer, vote-to-reopen

Can you allow us to view total re-open vote count in data explorer?

I am asking because I find it extremely hard to get questions re-opened by the community on lower traffic SE sites. Closed questions already have very low levels of traffic, so I find it extremely difficult to get the attention of five 3K+ rep users to vote within 4 days of each other to re-open a question.

Since we only get 1 reopen vote per the lifetime of a question, and [that vote can expire](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/123784/158605), I would like to be able to view the total number of re-open votes a question has received over a period of time so I can show moderators that a question actually has received many reopen votes, but they just haven't been within 4 days of each other.

I feel this would also be a useful tool for moderators who are on the fence about questions, because they could see how much (or how little) support the community has for a question which can aid them in deciding if a question should get re-opened or remain closed.

Comment: @CodyGray My problem is trying to re-open older questions that have over 100 views, like [this one](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/q/23075/1130). It has been significantly edited, the mods are aware of it, and a question was posted on meta about it, however we cannot get 5 votes within the 4 day timeframe and some re-open votes have already expired.

Comment: @CodyGray You mean more than 100 views, I think

Comment: +1 - I support this.  If SE is going to be successful, I think management is going to have to realize that some of these smaller sites might need some special treatment, or special access to information for their moderators.

Comment: Hmm. If the moderators are aware of it, *and* a question was posted on Meta about it, and you *still* can't get the required votes to re-open, might that be an indication that maybe it shouldn't be re-opened? I see how this might be a concern for some of the beta sites (which is what I thought you were referring to), but I don't think Programmers is small enough that there isn't a solid base of 3k+ users with re-open privileges. [Ack, and yes, I got things a bit mixed up in that first comment. Not worth correcting now.]

Comment: You should simply talk to your moderators on chat and ask them why it wasn't reopened.

Comment: @CodyGray This is not the only example. There are other questions I have tried getting re-opened and the moderators have told me that the question could go either way, and they'd rather leave it closed since they weren't sure. I was thinking a tool like this could assist moderators in making these kinds of decisions so they could see what kind of support a question has from the community, not just one vocal member.

Comment: Related: [Include successful Close and Reopen votes in the Votes table of Data.SE?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/160981/158605) and [Let SEDE users get hold of data on unsuccessful close votes for stats](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/83006/158605)