# Show successful close/reopen votes in SEDE regardless of if they've expired or not?

Tags: feature-request, vote-to-close, data-explorer, vote-to-reopen

Currently [Data.SE only show currently active close and reopen votes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/124716/158605). Once these votes expire, they're removed from the Votes table. This makes them rather useless when trying to query anything related to close or reopen votes in Data.SE.

Can successful close and reopen votes get stored in Data.SE instead of only currently active votes?

(I would actually like to see unsuccessful close/reopen votes in Data.SE as well, however [that proposal](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/83006/158605) has been [status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined))

Comment: @Mat The information is already available in the revision history, it's just not very convenient to use. And as the request mentions, the votes table already includes this information for currently active close/reopen votes at the time the data is transferred, which is rather confusing since that information isn't actually available in the UI.

Comment: @Mat The only votes with a UserId attached to them in Data.SE is Favorites and Bounties. All other vote types, including Close/Reopen votes, have a blank UserId

Comment: Also, for reference, getting the successful close votes for a particular user is [rather trivial](http://data.stackexchange.com/meta/query/90447?UserId=150235).

Comment: @TimStone Interesting query, I wasn't aware you could do that. I was playing around with it a bit and discovered it's fairly easy to get [a list of top close voters for a site](http://data.stackexchange.com/programmers/query/90843/top-close-voters)

Comment: @Rachel [as far as I can tell](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/162044/profile-page-shows-6-reopen-votes-total-while-i-have-at-least-25-successful-ones#comment471212_162044 "per discussion in other question") using PostHistory table is a workaround for this issue - is that correct?

Comment: @gnat That's a decent workaround if you're looking for a specific user's successful vote history, however if you're looking to run some queries on overall voting stats then you'll need to create a temp table and parse the PostHistory strings into your temp table, and that's a fairly expensive process. I'm not even sure if that would run at all on a big site like SO.

Comment: Can we have this? Right now there's not really any point in putting close votes in `Votes` at *all*, because it's useless.