# How to see the correctness of close/reopen votes?

Tags: support, vote-to-close, statistics, vote-to-reopen

How can I see the ratio of my previous close/reopen votes that were correct (i.e. resulted in the question being closed/reopened) or incorrect (i.e. resulted in the question left open/closed)?

I am interested in this statistic, because it would help self-educate about the correct use of close/reopen votes.

Comment: Are close votes public info exposed in [data.SE]?

Comment: @psubsee2003 No, they are anonomized.

Comment: @Servy Thanks. I know regular voting was but since close voting is semi-public info (once a post is closed and in the close vote queue), I wasn't sure about the close votes..

Comment: @psubsee2003 with some tweaking, SEDE allows to collect user stats on close / reopen votes ([as discussed eg here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/160981/165773)). these stats are kewed though, as there is no way to get it for deleted questions ([relatedfeature request here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/157462/165773)). I think at Programmers I have few thousands CVs that are "invisible" to SEDE due to deletion

Comment: @Servy not quite anonymized, my see comment above

Comment: Thank you @gnat :). This basically answers the question. I hope the reason that the ratio is so low are the deleted questions, otherwise I am in trouble :/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

We have this information internally, but intentionally avoid displaying it anywhere due to concerns that it would encourage problematic behavior. You should always strive to vote according to your conscience, based on an honest evaluation of the post and your understanding of what sorts of questions are appropriate for the site.

If you want to *improve* your understanding of these things based on the results of your previous close or re-open votes, you can find them listed on the Votes tab of your profile.

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that the data is available after all. You can see the questions you have successfully closed using [this query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/90447), and total close votes cast in the user profile, in this URL: https://stackoverflow.com/users/USER_ID?tab=votes&sort=closure.

For example my stats are 235 close votes, with 157 questions closed, or 66.8% correctedness<sup>(*)</sup>.

<sup>* *Rather poor stats, i know* :(</sup>

Comment: The close votes tab counts deleted posts, the query doesn't, which is going to account for a large percentage of the difference between those two numbers, and thus rendering the percentage you have there virtually meaningless, as it'll be off by so much.

Comment: Your actual % is somewhat higher than that.