# Reopen votes expiring too early?

Tags: bug, status-completed, vote-to-reopen

Per [this explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/123786/158605), reopen votes should expire at a rate of 1 per day after 4 days of no new reopen votes, providing the question has over 100 views.

But I've seen at least two cases now where this has not appeared to happen. A question will get additional reopen votes, and the votes start to expire immediately on the next day.

Two example questions are [this one](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/q/10211/316) which got its 3rd reopen vote 2 days ago and now has 1, and [this one](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/8730/how-do-i-deal-with-a-coworker-who-listens-to-the-radio-all-day?lq=1) (now deleted) which had the votes start to expire 1 day after it's 4th reopen vote.

In both cases, I was watching to see if they got enough reopen votes and expected to see a 4-day period after the last reopen vote before they started to expire, but saw votes start to expire sooner. I think they started to expire 4 days after the 1st reopen vote, even though they had subsequent reopen votes a few days afterwards, but I can't be positive of that.

Both example questions are for [The Workplace](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/), which is a beta site, so I am not sure if this only affects beta sites or not.

Is this a bug? Or did the policy for how votes expire change? Or did I just misunderstand the original explanation of how vote expiring works? Or perhaps I'm just going crazy... I didn't ask about this the first time I saw it happen because I figured I was just remembering things incorrectly, but now it's happened a 2nd time

Comment: I think re-open votes start expiring immediately after a few "keep closed" votes through /review.

Comment: there is a chance that amount of views might impact expiration - if memory serves, I once was explained that was the case for close votes. though, if this is the case, I'd consider it a bug: I understand how amount of views expires close votes but doing the same for reopen votes somehow doesn't feel right

Comment: @gnat Close and reopen votes won't expire if the question has less than 100 views. That's the only view-related thing I know of that affects vote expiration.

Comment: @Yannis I'd be interested in finding out if that is indeed the case. Do you know if subsequent reopen votes will put the post back in the Reopen queue after it's been kicked out?

Comment: According to [this answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/139836/162704), close votes start ageing immediately after three "Do Not Close" review votes. Can't find a reference for the reverse, but I imagine it works the same way. No idea what happens if there are subsequent close / re-open votes.

Comment: @Yannis That answer specifically states that *"if someone visits the question directly and votes to close it, that'll both count toward the 5 votes needed to close it and stall the aging for another four days"*, so if that is the case than this is indeed a bug.

Comment: @Rachel Except if three more people voted through review and restarted the ageing process.

Comment: hey! "[this one](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/q/10211/316)" has *my* reopen vote, I just can't remember if I cast after rev 3 or rev 6

Comment: @Yannis I'm not sure I understand what you're suggesting. A new reopen or close vote should stall the aging for 4 days, however in at least 2 cases now I have seen votes start to expire a day after the most recent vote

Comment: @gnat It tells me I already voted to reopen the question so I can't vote again, and Chad said in [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/8591359#8591359) that it has his reopen vote, but all 3 of us don't show up in the Reopen vote history the last time it was reopened from being too-localized. Perhaps I can assume the 3 reopen votes it had were from you, me, and Chad?

Comment: @Rachel yes it seems so. Looks like 2 reopen votes were _abducted by aliens_ in about 7 days, since Mar 13 (rev 3 is dated Mar 13, and per my recollection I voted rather at about that time, though I am not sure)

Comment: @Rachel Three "keep closed" review votes would kickstart ageing. A new re-open vote would stall it. Then three more "keep closed" review votes would kickstart it again. And round and round it goes...

Comment: @Yannis Yes, but per [the answer you linked](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/139834/what-exactly-happens-with-the-new-do-not-close/139836#139836), subsequent votes after it's been kicked out of the queue should "stall the aging for another four days", not continue the aging process where it left off or stop it from resetting upon subsequent votes.

Comment: To be more specific they start expiring *next day* after the "Do Not Close/Reopen" option activates, a vote isn't immediately taken away, from my experience.

Comment: @BenBrocka The first example question got it's first reopen vote quite a few days ago, and I do not think it would have taken a few days for the question to get reviewed. The reopen queue is handled fairly quickly, even on smaller sites. Perhaps getting kicked out of the queue starts the 4-day timer which cannot get reset?

Comment: I could swear I've seen reopen votes expire faster than 4 days on workplace in a similar situation but I could be wrong

Comment: FYI: Review won't ever *hasten* aging - it'll just allow it to start happening at all.

Comment: I have seen this problem also, hope @Shog9 and the gang can solve this bug, I hate my reopen votes fading away.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Alright, two things.

1. There was a recent bug which chose the latest close/reopen vote on a question that *did have* old, ageable votes - the developer will be chastised when he returns from [his vacation](http://www.bignerdranch.com/index).
2. The [original spec](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/97594) never worked the way it said - once the 100 page view requirement was met, any close/reopen vote older than 4 days was eligible to be aged, starting with the most recent ageable vote.

After the next build, the functionality will behave like [the spec says](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/97594); it will also choose the oldest vote to be aged.

Comment: since bug affected Workplace, the developer should be [slapped](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/8578455#8578455 "click here if you wonder why is that")