# Do reopen votes have an expiry time?

Tags: support, vote-to-reopen

Once I asked a question but unfortunately it got closed. So I edited my post and voted for it it to be reopened. 2 days later I got 4 votes, but never got the last one. Yesterday I spotted that the count of votes oddly dropped to 2, and today only 1 remains.

What's the matter? Can voters retract their votes? I tested this, but it seems there is no way to retract my reopen-vote.

So I suspect that reopen-votes have an expiry time. Is it true?

Comment: Yes, close and re-open votes age away after 4 days on questions with more than 100 views.

Comment: @Yannis worth to mention that it never worked as expected, [until two weeks ago](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/172738/152859). :)

Comment: @Yannis I see, thank you. Besides, I spot that the delete-votes still exist.

Comment: I think delete votes never expire.

Comment: Yes delete votes don't expire, not many delete voters around (even on SO) for delete votes to expire.