# Why don't delete votes expire?

Tags: discussion, vote-to-delete, vote-to-reopen

According to [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/172661/reopen-votes-expiring-too-early/172738#172738), reopen-votes have an expiry time (4 days) whenever the post has more than 100 viewers. However, another fact is that delete votes never expire, and only 3 such votes are required for deletion. Reopening requires 5 votes however.

So it is far easier for a closed question to be deleted than to be reopened, even after some improvements. Isn't that somewhat unfair?

Comment: Far easier? That would only be the case if a site has the same number of close/re-open voters and delete voters, which obviously can't be.

Comment: Delete votes can only be cast by 15k+ users...there are not *that*many around.

Comment: Even un-delete never expires....

Comment: Probably because relatively speaking they're so crazy rare, especially on sites other than Stack Overflow, far less things would end up deleted

Comment: hm per my recollection, [one of my questions](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/109912/165773 "this one") had a delete vote displayed for a while, but month or two (maybe three) later it somehow disappeared

Comment: @gnat can't be, users can't cast delete vote before question is closed and if moderator cast a delete vote on open question the delete is instant. Most likely what you saw was a close vote which expired after fours days.

Comment: Because there's no sense in [fixing what's not broken](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9431/why-is-it-possible-to-vote-for-deletion-undeletion-more-than-once/9438#9438), but also probably because [Jeff thought they did](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9431/why-is-it-possible-to-vote-for-deletion-undeletion-more-than-once/42644#42644).

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd I see. Most likely you're right, my memory could have failed on that old question