# Questions about "Close Votes"

Tags: discussion, review, vote-to-close

1. What's the difference between the "Leave Open" and "Skip" options which is show when you do the "Review Close Votes"? I understand the meaning of "Leave Open" and "Skip" - but was wondering what difference does chosing either of these options have on the close vote itself.
2. When I look at my votes tab of my user pages, I see on entry as "closure(deleted)" instead of the usual "closure". What does this mean?

EDIT: 2nd question answered in Comments by ShaWizDowArd "As for your second point it means your close vote was "deleted", or more accurate to say expired. This happens when there are no further close votes for 4 days, then the votes start to expire, one every day."

Comment: "Skip" means that you don't have an opinion you want to share. "Leave Open" means you think the question should not be closed.

Comment: @DanielFischer - I know that, but does it have a different impact on the close votes?

Comment: Well, "Skip" is neutral, and three "Leave Open" kick the post out of the queue.

Comment: @DanielFischer - ok thank you - that's what I was looking for. Just one clarification - I am assuming it kicks it out of everyone's queue, right? Any idea about the 2nd Q?

Comment: As for your second point it means your close vote was "deleted", or more accurate to say expired. This happens when there are no further close votes for 4 days, then the votes start to expire, one every day.

Comment: @user93353: It's best to limit question posts to be one actual question. You're probably better off splitting that second question out to its own post.

Comment: "Closure (deleted)" seems a bit buggy, since I'm seeing it on questions that are closed, which show my vote, and which have fewer than 100 views anyway (which, IIRC, means the votes don't expire).

Comment: While reviewing close votes click on `(more)`. It will guide you.

Comment: @user93353 Everyone's queue. You only get the same question once no matter what you choose. (Choosing "skip" means "skip permanently", it doesn't mean "decide later".)

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd - thank you for the answer to the 2nd question.

Comment: @Wooble interesting, can you post link to such a question?

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15724954/python-advanced-search-library

Comment: @Wooble assuming you see "deleted" next to your closure vote, if you cast that vote on March 31st then it probably expired by now and the vote you see there now was probably cast after your expired.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/97581/135736 suggests they shouldn't expire if the question has fewer than 100 views, although this may be out of date information.

Comment: @Wooble true, it even [got love and attention](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/172738/152859) very recently. Hmm... so maybe three high rep users chose "Leave Open" thus dismissing your vote then somebody cast a new one since.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The "Skip" option is neutral, it has no further effect (and does not increase your review count).

A "Leave Open" vote counts as a review, and contributes to taking a post out of the close votes queue - after three "Leave Open" votes, the question is removed from the queue (but the close votes it has still persist, and it can be closed from the question page itself).

I'm not sure what the "closure(deleted)" is supposed to mean, it does *not* mean that the question you voted to close has (ever) been deleted, and it can't mean that the vote expired either, since I have some "(deleted)" on votes that participated in closing the question (which never was deleted).

Comment: I'm pretty sure that `closure(deleted)` means the vote to close has expired and been deleted. I know successful close votes are deleted from Data.SE (feature-request to change that [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/160981/158605)), so it is likely that behavior is the same for the database that page pulls its data from. I also found a [bug](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/172661/158605) fairly recently where it was confirmed that the wrong close votes would sometimes expire, which may be why you might have sometimes seen a questionable pattern in which votes were deleted.

Answer (score 4):

> What's the difference between the "Leave Open" and "Skip" options?

*"Leave open"* means like "This question shouldn't be closed".

"*Skip"* means "I'm not 100% sure this question should close or not, so I'm skipping it. I don't want to see it on my voting queue."

> When I look at my votes tab of my user pages, I see on entry as
>   "closure(deleted)" instead of the usual "closure". What does this
>   mean?

It doesn't mean the question you voted to close has ever been deleted. And also close votes can be expired.

- If the question has less than 100 views, the votes never expire
- If the question has more than 100 views, close votes expire at a rate of one every 4 days.

[Close Votes expire too soon for low-traffic tags](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/97556/close-votes-expire-too-soon-for-low-traffic-tags)

Comment: It's definitely nothing to do with deleted questions; these don't show up on your Votes list at all.

Comment: @Wooble Thank you. Updated `;)`