# How do re-open votes expire?

Tags: discussion, vote-to-reopen

How do re-open votes expire?

I couldn't find anything in the help center, but I did find https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/123786/38765

I voted to re-open [How to follow only specific issues on Github, instead of watching an entire project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14140564/how-to-follow-only-specific-issues-on-github-instead-of-watching-an-entire-proj#comment25246053_14140564) on June 30, and my re-open vote has expired.

It's possible, but seems unlikely, that the question has been viewed 100 times since I voted to re-open (it's currently at 230 views).

Does a re-open vote expire when a question has been viewed 100 times since the vote has been cast, and a day has passed, or is a day passing sufficient when the question has been viewed 100 times, ever, even if those views were before the re-open vote was cast?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The game has changed since that answer. With the new Reopen Votes queue, vote aging can start much more quickly than before. Once three users vote to leave a question closed, review on the question completes and **the aging process starts immediately**, no matter how old it is or how many views it has. Since reopen reviews get completed fairly quickly, reopen votes will almost always start aging away the same day.

That question was reviewed and left closed the same day you cast your reopen vote: https://stackoverflow.com/review/reopen/2413909

So, assuming there were no other reopen votes, your vote would have expired a maximum of four days after that review completed.

Comment: And in this new "game rules" can I re-cast my reopen vote?

Comment: @Rikard No, you can never re-cast reopen votes.