# Availability of site historical statistics

Tags: discussion, statistics, time

I'm relatively new here and have been finding my way around - at present I'm getting a kick out of the whole "helping the community" thing.
I've noticed the "Closed Votes" queue seems to be quite big (and seems to be getting bigger), but I've got no context for making this judgement.  Googing around it seems like the consensus is that this queue is actually getting smaller!
I was wondering if there were any historical statistics available which showed "key site health indicators" (I'm too green to even know if the "Closed Votes" queue count would... erm... count as such) and their progression through time?  Something to give context to a newbie.
I suspect that if there were, people might find them strangely motivating, in much the same way as badges...

Comment: You can check out the [Stack Exchange Data Explorer](http://data.stackexchange.com/), where you can write your own queries to find out almost anything you want. Some interesting queries are [here](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/queries).

Comment: @DavidRobinson Thank you - I didn't know that existed.  Having scanned the table list though, I don't think this will provide the information I'm alluding to; for example, I can't see anything which would give me the "Close Vote" queue count at given points in time - the data would seem to lean towards "what is state of the system now" type queries.  If I've got this wrong, please kick me!

Comment: @GHC If the data dump/date explorer contained a reviews table it might have enough information to be able to determine historical queue sizes, but you're right: it does not. I thought there was an outstanding feature-request to add them, but searching now I wasn't able to find it.

Comment: @JeremyBanks Actually, looking at it again, it might be possible to determine the example query I've stated: We've got Votes where VoteTypeID = 6 (which are close votes, and which have date: CreationDate) linked to Posts via Postid.  Posts have ClosedDate.  This might just scrape it, but first I'll have to read up on all the scenarios for how a post might be flagged to be closed, maybe closed , maybe reopened.  Nothing is every easy :)

Comment: I don't think the data includes close votes that didn't actually cause a question to be closed, (see [Let SEDE users get hold of data on unsuccessful close votes for stats](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/83006)). If a close vote was cast before the close vote queue was created, the close vote may have expired (depending on the views of the question and date of the votes) before the queue was created so the question would never have been put in the queue. Also, *if* I recall correctly the "50k" figure is somewhat artificial; the Stack Exchange team manually adds old close-voted questions.