# Add close reasons to the data dump and to Data Explorer

Tags: feature-request, data-explorer, data-dump, close-reasons

We already have the close votes (`VoteTypeId` = 6), but there aren't any close reasons associated with each vote.

Comment: This is a semi-internal request: @waffles wanted to track this on Meta.

Comment: It would also be nice if the close vote reconstruction script is run on SEDE as well.

Comment: I think I have the kind of [query](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/193616) you want. It’s definitely already implemented.

Answer (score 6):

### Why should this query be closed?

o **exact duplicate**
This query covers exactly the same ground as other queries for these data; the other queries retrieve the data more efficiently.

o **off topic**
Queries on the Stack Exchange Data Explorer are expected to generally relate to Stack Exchange in some way, within the scope defined in the [faq](https://data.stackexchange.com/faq). Queries unrelated to Stack Exchange will not be successful, regardless of how many unicorns or waffles were involved in their creation.

o **not constructive**
This query is not a good fit to our archived data format. We expect queries to generally request data that people would care about; this query will likely solicit zero interest.

o **not a real query**
It's difficult to tell what is being asked for here. This query is poorly formatted, overly inefficient or syntactically incorrect and cannot be reasonably executed in its current form.

o **too localized**
This query is unlikely to ever help any future visitors; it is only relevant to a small geographic area, a specific moment in time, or an extraordinarily narrow situation that is not generally applicable to any of the sixteen people who will ever visit SEDE.

Comment: Ok, I guess the off-topic part makes sense, but can we have a migration path to Stack Exchange Unicorn Explorer?

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't give you the reasons for *individual* close votes, but there is a query on data explorer that associates a user to closed questions and the combined close reason: https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/s/792/how-many-questions-have-i-helped-to-close

e.g.:

```
Close Reason                 Count 
---------------------------- ----- 
Not a real question          252   
Off topic                    241   
Exact duplicate              118   
Subjective and argumentative 56    
Too localized                27    
(Total)                      694
```

I'm guessing you're after the full breakdown by reason, though, and that doesn't seem to be available. I will note that per-user reasons aren't displayed on the site, either, whereas "closed as ... by ..." is displayed. So I believe this request would technically expose additional information beyond what's currently public.

Comment: Did you see the OP's first comment? "This is a semi-internal request: @waffles wanted to track this on Meta."

Comment: Yes. I read that as "the request originates internally, not just something I want for fun". If it's intended as strictly-internal access to the data, then nevermind that part. :]

Comment: Sounds good. I wasn't sure, myself; just wanted to point it out.

Comment: Also, it's not obvious that the data can currently be extracted even for the query I linked to, so the answer was partly for the benefit of anyone who finds this question from a search and might find it useful.

Comment: The request is for the data to be made public. The request itself originated through internal discussion.