# Unable to retrieve number of close votes before year 2011

Tags: support, vote-to-close, data-explorer

The Stack Overflow schema says that `VoteTypeId` field in the `Votes` table corresponds to the type of vote received and`VoteTypeId = 6` indicates a `close` vote. I am trying to find the number of `close` votes every year. However, I notice that such information is not present for year [2008, 2009 and 2010](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/116256) but present for 2011 and 2012. For example, [sql query for 2011](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/116257) gives me

```
VoteTypeId         
---------- ------- 
1          802092  
2          6647571 
3          461186  
4          21      
5          650191  
6          143608  
7          808     
8          14174   
9          14073   
10         389150  
11         24667   
12         702     
15         117065  
16         142198  

(14 row(s) affected)
```

while a [2010](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/116256) query returns

```
VoteTypeId         
---------- ------- 
1          469309  
2          4204926 
3          257103  
4          200     
5          387225  
8          8644    
9          8590    
10         199929  
11         13466   
12         538     
15         965     

(11 row(s) affected)
```

Surprisingly, 2010 and before do not have any votes for `VoteTypeId = 6`. Is there a reason for such a behavior?

Comment: After a certain amount of time (and other criteria), close votes expire (they're aged out and no longer active). They're still recorded somewhere (because you can't re-vote to close a question you had previously voted on if your vote has expired), but they might be removed from that table.

Comment: @Mat, Thanks for your patience. Apologies, I deleted my previous comment by accident. If I understand correctly according to this answer by Jeff [0], a close vote will not expire if it would have less than a 100 views. Is it safe to assume that these changes where only implemented in 2011, since Jeff's answer is dated July 6 2011? I would also like to understand what was the mechanism for close vote expiration prior to 2011.

[0] http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/97581/214223

Comment: See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/83006/let-sede-users-get-hold-of-data-on-unsuccessful-close-votes-for-stats and http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/74431/stats-about-close-reasons-used for related info. Before the change, I believe close vote simply expired after 4 days.

Comment: Thank You. I think I will safely assume that votes before 2011 are not  available. However, I think I may be able to reengineer them from the `PostHistory` table. Such an approach however may be complex and not 100% accurate.

Comment: I don't think so. Only completed closures would be in there.

Comment: Yes exactly, that will give me some sort of an idea but won't quite be  accurate. I think I will give a pass on such a statistic. Thank You very much for your patience!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Close votes [expire](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/97556/close-votes-expire-too-soon-for-low-traffic-tags/97581#97581), and when they do they are no longer accessible in the `Votes` table on Data Explorer. (Before June 2011, close votes simply expired after four days, so there is no chance at all to have a record of votes prior to that now.)

Making this information available [has been requested](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/83006/let-sede-users-get-hold-of-data-on-unsuccessful-close-votes-for-stats), but was declined. So you can't find that information on Data Explorer. The post history table won't help you there, an entry is made in that table only if a question is successfully closed/reopened. Expired votes won't register anything in there.