# How to find total number of questions closed by each reason?

Tags: support, closed-questions, data-explorer, statistics

Is there any way to get a total of all questions on a given site that have been closed for each reason? E.g.,

- 123 duplicate
- 456 OT
- 789 too broad

Bonus points if OT is separated by its reasons.

Comment: The query in the original request gives back weird results but looks essentially fine. Can be improved, but better as edit to the answer or a new answer in there. :)

Comment: @ShadowWizard I took your hint and added an [improved answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/245901/158100) on that post